# How to highlight a whole cell when hovering over link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, highlight, css-tables

I have a horizontal nav bar where I would like to highlight the entire cell the link is in when I hover over the link, however, I can only get the immediate area around the text to highlight. I would greatly appreciate any pointers on how I can achieve this.

Here is my JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PYKXb/1/

This is my CSS code:

```
#horizontal-style {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}

#horizontal-style li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:auto;
    padding:1%;
}

#horizontal-style a:link {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
    padding:none;
    background:#ebebec;
    color:#005da4;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:90%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#horizontal-style a:visited {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto ;
    padding:none;
    background: #ebebec;
    color:#005da4;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:90%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#horizontal-style a:hover {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto ;
    padding:none;
    background: #acce39;
    color:#005da4;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:90%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#horizontal-style a:hover {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto ;
    padding:none;
    background: #acce39;
    color:#005da4;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:90%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<ul id="horizontal-style">
    <li><a href=# >Home</a></li>
    <li><a href=# >About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href=# >Online<br />Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href=# >Registration</a></li>
    <li><a href=# >Faculty</a></li>
    <li><a href=# >Calendar</a></li>
    <li><a href=# >Store</a></li>
    <li><a href=# >Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href=# >Online<br/>Lectures</a></li>
    <li><a href=# >Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href=# >Forum</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't you build a demo fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net it just helps the process along. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the link above my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine, have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wkxjY/)

```css
#horizontal-style li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:auto;
    padding:1%;
    background:#ebebec;
}
#horizontal-style li:hover{
    background-color:#acce39;
}
```

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you so much! It solves my issue for the most part. Any chance you could help me center the text in the highlighted cell. All the 'a' styles have 'text-align: center;' as an attribute, however the highlight appears to skew to the right, particularly on wide screens.

Comment: It's not make whole cell to hyperlink. It's only do for text

Comment: Add text-align:center to the li

Answer (score 2):

Simply move padding from `li` to `a` and add `width` and `height` equals to `100%`

```
#horizontal-style a:link {
   padding: 1%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   ...
   ...
}
```

It makes **whole of cell** hyperlink.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aepKP/

Comment: While I like how you made the whole box, is there a way to keep the text vertically aligned? It seems all that code is still there, but its not working now.

Comment: It appears that the height attribute in the 'a' style is what is disabling the vertical align.

Answer (score 1):

You have used a lot of repetitive and unnecessary CSS in your code. Try optimizing that.
Secondly, an alternative, in my opinion, to achieve this, is to use a parent "div" tag to enclose your menu in.
All the "li" tags inside "ul" tags can be floated left. (this gives a horizontal menu look)
All the link tags "a" inside your "li" tags can be made to "display : block" style in your CSS, with your desired width.
So, now when you change the "hover" state of the links using CSS with changing the "background color", the whole selected width of yours turns its color.

Hope this helps !

CSS:

```
#menubar{
height:50px;
background:#000000;
margin-top:100px;
padding-top:15px;
padding-left:20px;
}
ul{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
#menubar ul li{

float:left;
}
#menubar ul li:hover a{
background:#fff;
}
#menubar ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
display:block;
width:150px;
text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menubar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">A</a></li>
<li><a href="#">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#">C</a></li>
<li><a href="#">D</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While I appreciate the cleanliness, can you get it to highlight some padding around it so it extends above and below rather than just side to side? When I've tried to do this on my own, I've been getting some staircase like look between links.

Comment: It can be done easily. Just add the following to your CSS for "a" link elements "padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;" or as required.